# How to know when a user logs in

Tags: 2010

In SharePoint 2010, how would you know if someone has logged in?

I looked at the SDK and with the new User Profiles and Social Data sdk, I wasn't able to find this.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. You could enable 'view' audit logging and look for events for a user in the Audit log.

Answer (score 0):

how bout creating your own login form and simply track that ?

[Writing a Custom forms login for Sharepoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/22/writing-a-custom-forms-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010-part-2.aspx)

Comment: I think this would be the obvious route to take. I was hoping with the new Social Data / UserProfiles  SDK that they would have some sort of an event we can subscribe to. Something very fundamental to social data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an HTTPModule and track the user yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a HttpModule with the activity feed infrastructure, to get regular updates in a user's feed of, for example, what page they were looking at.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/activityfeedsconsole

```
public class ActivityFeedHttpModule : IHttpModule {
    public virtual void Init(HttpApplication app) {
        app.EndRequest += new EventHandler(app_EndRequest);
    }
    private void app_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        bool createevent = true; //do some logic here to only log event every 30 mins based on cookie or something
        if(createevent) {   
            SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(aSite);
            UserProfileManager m_UPM = new UserProfileManager(context);
            string username = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
            UserProfile userProfile = m_UPM.GetUserProfile(username);       
            ActivityEvent activityEvent = ActivityEvent.CreateActivityEvent(m_ActivityManager, activityType.ActivityTypeId, owner, publisher);
            activityEvent.Name = activityType.ActivityTypeName;
            activityEvent.ItemPrivacy = (int)Privacy.Public;
            activityEvent.Owner = owner;
            activityEvent.Publisher = publisher; 
            Link link = new Link();
            link.Href = siteUrl;
            link.Name = communityName;
            activityEvent.Link = link;  
            activityEvent.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```